# Laravel queue class being called correctly but the method is not working

Tags: php, laravel

This is the handle on the job class

```
public function handle(Request $request)
{
    if (strpos($request->status, 'Approved') !== false) {

        $client = new Client();

        $client->request('POST', 'http://localhost:5000/api/email', [
            'headers' => [
                'Athentication' => 'ASOIDjhoiqwjheoiwqjeqhowE21323ijosadiweqjeoi',
            ],
            'json' => [
                'type' => $request->type
            ]
        ]);
    }
}
```

And this is where the job is being called on the controller:

```
public function update(UpdateRequest $request)
{
    $redirect_location = parent::updateCrud($request);
    PostEmail::dispatch($request);

    return $redirect_location;
}
```

I'm using Amazon SQS, everything is configured correctly and the job gets called on.

I tried running `php artisan queue:work` and letting it run, and then I tried `php artisan queue:listen`, both of them work but I get the same issue..

This is the result for `queue:work`

> [2019-02-08 17:18:21][78272a19-cd7c-4787-8c61-0ab1206ef203]
> Processing: App\Jobs\PostEmail
>
> [2019-02-08  17:18:21][78272a19-cd7c-4787-8c61-0ab1206ef203] Processed:
> App\Jobs\PostEmail

So, the job gets called upon, but never really executed. I don't know why!

Comment: Maybe you can add a `failed()` method on your job and see if an exception is being thrown. See [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#dealing-with-failed-jobs). In the failed method, you could just `Log($exception)`.

Comment: Doesn't it keep a log by default?

Comment: have you looked to add an `else` after your `if(strpos($request->status, 'Approved') !== false)` and checking to see if that outputs? If no errors are showing up when you process the job, maybe it is failing the `if` statement and moving on, which is why you see no output or errors.

Comment: Or you could also just add a `Log::infi('Handling job')` as the first line in your `handle()` method to see if the job is being handled. If it outputs anything in your log, then your conditional statement is failing instead.

Comment: @Mozammit I'm 100% sure my statement is not failing, but that's a good idea, I'll try it out, thanks.